# Google Map Layer Effect

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-styling

I'm created a div and embed Google Map code.

Like this:

[image]

But, i want make effect on my Google map.

[image]

But i don't know Google Map Api.

Have easy way or other soluitons? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the style of your map.  In this case you probably just want to set the Saturation to -100.

For a static map, the url might be: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0,0&zoom=2&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x480&maptype=roadmap&style=saturation:-100

For a dynamic map, just create a style and pass it into your map options:

```
var styles = [
  {
    stylers: [
      { saturation: -100 }
    ]
  }
]

var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.5,-122.5),
  styles : styles
}

var map = map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#style_syntax). Everything is mentioned in there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link where you can style the maps: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

I just did this one and it should look very similar.

```
    var styles = [
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#a0a0a0" },
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#c9c8c8" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#e3e3e3" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#434443" },
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#f7f9fb" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#ffffff" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#d6d5d5" },
      { "visibility": "on" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      { "color": "#434443" }
    ]
  },{
  }
];

map.setOptions({styles: styles});
```